# How to install Windows to a computer with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

Ubuntu is currently installed on my computer and I want to install Windows 7 alongside it. On my computer there are three HDDs:

- 2x  500GB
- 8GB SSD

I have already installed Ubuntu on one of the 500GB HDDs. I installed Windows Environment on Ubuntu so I can run the .exe files. I tried to start the setup.exe file to install Windows on my other disk but it says:

> Windows Setup cannot find a location to store temporary installation files. To install Windows, make sure that a partition on your boot disk has at least 829 megabytes of free space.

I understand that there is no root permission so I cannot run Windows installer. Also I used GParted for Windows to see my other HDD with different types like FAT32, NTFS or others. But it is not working. I tried to reboot from Windows disk but it is passing directly to Ubuntu.

How would I go about setting this up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work. You cannot install Windows through Wine. You'll have to burn a Windows installation DVD, boot your computer from this disk and click through the Windows installer.

**Edit:** To be more explicit here: Wine resembles a whole Windows Environment, not just an interpreter for `*.exe` files. What you're trying to accomplish would be like installing Windows inside of an already running Windows installation.

Comment: I tried to boot from Windows installation. I made my DVD driver first boot option. But it is not booting from DVD. It passes and starts to start Ubuntu. So I cannot boot from Wİndows installation DVD. Also I'm using Samsung NP700G7C laptop and my BIOS is as follows.
OEM String[0] : AAABAAAAAWAA
OEM String[1] : 2012/07/20
OEM String[2] : SECPARTN:AAB
Part number : AAB
BIOS Vendor : American Megatrends Inc.
BIOS Release date : 2012-11-12
BIOS Version : P08AAB.117.121112.DK
Product name : 700G7C
System enclosure type : SYSTEM_TYPE_LAPTOP
MICOM vendor : MICOM_VENDOR_SMSC

Comment: Try downloading a fresh ISO image (they actually exist, that's not a call for copyright infringement, just ask Google for "Windows", "ISO" and "Download" with `site:microsoft.com`) and booting this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just install Windows alongside Ubuntu that way. You have to download the windows iso and burn to CD as the answer of @AndreasWiese.

But what i want to talk about is different.

If you have installed Ubuntu on one harddisk then you have two options to install windows:

1. Replace Ubuntu if you installed windows on the same harddisk of Ubuntu or if you are advanced user you can shrink the Ubunru partitions using `gparted` and make space to install windows on it. **But** here you have to pay attention that you'll loose your GRUB and hence you can't boot ubuntu gain because the Widnows installer will never understand the Linux file system so you have to fix the Grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows This is a link that will help you if you choose this decision.
2. Install Windows on the second harddrive and this is not installing alongside technically since each OS will have its own resources and space. This is the easiest choice to go through **but**  you have here to pay attention for something. You can't swap between Windows and Ubuntu that easily since each boot loader will be installed on a separate HDD. Now if you are advanced user you can still add entries of windows in GRUB2 menu but if you are not you have mainly to choose from your BIOS the main harddrive(OS) to boot by default and when you have to boot in the other you have to change the boot order.

Hope that helped you.